# .SAV live video?

Tags: file-formats, camera

I bought a camera that I plan on using for my videos. The problem? It streams over the network, live, in a format that I've never even heard of.

**.sav**

I've tried everything, and I don't know how to get it to a format that something can read. What is this format, and what can read it?

Comment: What kind of camera is it?

Comment: I bought a Lowes iris camera. I'm doing a production with "survailence" like footage, and I thought that rather than do editing to make it look like that, just buy a camera that does it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From everything I can see, this is a proprietary format with no third party software that can open the files.  Does the software that came with camera allow you to export footage as a more compatible format?  It would be up to the manufacturer to be providing a software package that can save out a standard video format.